# load data from sd return java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

[image: JPG File Location]

The screen shot above show the path for my JPG file-/mnt/sdcard.

I try to load the image but it returnd java.lang.nullpointerexception. Below is my code.

```
String imagefile ="/mnt/sdcard/KFC_Voucher.JPG";
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagefile);
image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Please help.

Comment: probably posting the logcat.. would be more helpful...

Comment: im testing from my phone...and appreciate if someone explains why this post voted down....

Comment: If you're testing from your phone and aren't hooked up to a development environment, download a logcat viewer to determine what's happening. There are several free logcat viewers in the Android market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.id.image has  to be in the layout you set trough setContentView(), else findViewById will return null